# State undefined even with initial state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I declared a state named `product` with initial values.
However it appears as undefined once before loading the new values.
This causes problems when I want to map its value.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { LOAD_PRODUCT } from "./GraphQL/Queries";

import Product from './Components/Product';

function App() {

    const { error, loading, data } = useQuery(LOAD_PRODUCT)
    const [product, setProduct] = useState<Product>({
      node: {
        id: 0,
        title: "Test"
      }
    })
    
    useEffect(() => {
         setProduct(data)
     }, [data])


    if(loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>

    console.log(product)

  return (
    <>
    <Product product={product}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: Since it logged after the loading state, it might be the transition of data, not related to initial value. Logging before the loading state should be ok. Please just create a reproducible example in a sandbox. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Moreover you just duplicating the state, there should be some initial value API you can pass to `useQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm assuming `data` is undefined before it's fetched from your database. And therefore `loading` returns `true` meanwhile.
Since `loading = true` before `data` is available, your component is returning `<h1>Loading...</h1>`. And therefore is not reaching your `console.log(product)`
. I suspect that if you move `console.log(product)` to right before the  `if(loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>`, you'll get the result you need. So in the beginning it WILL print out the initial value, however it will change the initial value to undefined (using `setProduct`) after that, and finally when the data is fetched it'll `setProduct` to the `data`. Let me know if that works out for you, I played with the code a little bit on my end.